# Why does VLC player lag after being paused?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, vlc-media-player

On Ubuntu, why when I pause VLC player and then start it after a few seconds, part of the movie doesn't play and jumps forward? This problem didn't occur with Windows.

Someone said that version 2 or 4 might solve the problem, it was true that version 4 would solve the problem, but when the video paused, the subtitles would disappear. Now I want to install version 2 but I can't find it anywhere, does anyone have a solution?

Comment: version 4?? How are you enumerating the versions. Current is 3.0.14. Does it do this on all videos, or just some? I'm a frequent user on Mac & Windows & I've never known this to happen, but never tried it on nix.

Comment: @Tetsujin No, apparently there is version 4 in the snap store and some people had similar problems to me. see this: https://www.reddit.com/r/VLC/comments/8oiwu9/303_stutterlag_when_resuming_after_pause_also/

Comment: There is no version 4. I don't know the snap store, but your source for VLC builds is https://www.videolan.org That brief reddit thread is from 2 years & 11 updates ago & has nothing but vague mumbling.

Comment: Not that this solves your problem but this is one of the many reasons I moved from VLC to [SMPlayer](https://www.smplayer.info/).  I never have a problem with it and it is way more performant IMHO.  To be fair though.. I have had a few corrupted movies that I could still get to play through VLC.. otherwise SMPlayer always seems to do a better job.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas This player does not open subtitle files, I do not know why it does not show any reaction

Comment: I have no such problem with SMPlayer as long as the `SRT` files match the movie file name.  The `v` key (by default) turns them on and off.. I must use it differently than you. :)  If SMPlayer doesn't work for you.. cool.. I am just trying to tell you what eased my frustration. You can also load the SRT files "by hand"

Comment: Are the video files on an external HDD, which spins down?